# React infinite re-render: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

so i have a React component that renders a table with some data and the table has some filter components in order to update the data.
here is the component:

```
const DoctorTable = ({ onChange, value }: RichDoctorSelectProps) => {
  const [allDataSources, setAllDataSources] = useState<
    { page: number; items: TDataSource }[]
  >([]);
  const [uiData, setUiData] = useState<UIData>({
    latitude,
    longitude,
    page: 1,
    search: undefined,
    specialityIds: [],
    city: undefined,
    zipcode: undefined,
    country: undefined,
  });

  const {
    items: dataSource,
    refetch: refetchDoctorProjections,
  } = useDoctorProjections({
    input: uiToInput(uiData),
    locale: Locale.DeDe,
  });

  const onUpdateFilter = (filters: {
    address?: TAddressValue;
    specialityIds?: string[];
  }) => {
    // filter logic here
    setUiData({
      ...uiData,
      ...updatedFilters,
      page: 1,
    });
  };
  const onSearchSubmit = (search: string) => {
    setUiData((prevUiData) => ({
      ...prevUiData,
      search,
      page: 1,
    }));
    // refetch data
  };
  const onSearchClear = () => {
    setUiData({
      ...uiData,
      search: undefined,
      page: 1,
    });
  };

  const noSearchAndNoFilters =
    !uiData.search &&
    !uiData.specialityIds &&
    !uiData.city &&
    !uiData.country &&
    !uiData.zipcode;
  const hasSearch = uiData.search;
  const hasFilters =
    (uiData.specialityIds || []).length > 0 ||
    uiData.city ||
    uiData.country ||
    uiData.zipcode;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (uiData.page >= 1 && dataSource.length > 0) {
      const isPageAdded = allDataSources.some(
        (pageData) => pageData.page === uiData.page,
      );
      if (hasFilters || hasSearch || noSearchAndNoFilters) {
        setAllDataSources((prevItems) => [
          { page: 1, items: dataSource },
        ]);
      } else if (!isPageAdded) {
        if (uiData.page === 1) {
          setAllDataSources([{ page: 1, items: dataSource }]);
        } else {
          setAllDataSources((prevItems) => [
            ...prevItems,
            { page: uiData.page, items: dataSource },
          ]);
        }
      }
    }
  }, [dataSource]);

  const table = (
    <Table
      value={selectedDoctor}
      dataSource={allDataSources.flatMap((pageData) => pageData.items)}
      isLoading={loading && uiData.page === 1}
      isCalled={called}
      onRowClick={onChange}
      hasMore={uiData.page < total}
      onLoadMore={() => setUiData({ ...uiData, page: uiData.page + 1 })}
    />
  );

  const filters = (
    <Filters
      searchValue={uiData.search}
      onSearchSubmit={onSearchSubmit}
      onSearchClear={onSearchClear}
      onUpdateFilter={onUpdateFilter}
    />
  );

  return (
    <div className={cn.root}>
      {filters}
      {table}
    </div>
  );
};

export { DoctorTable };
```

also the table component is inside a wrapper component that handles infinite scrolling, so the problem is whenever i trigger `onSearchSubmit` or `onSearchClear` or `onUpdateFilter`, it causes infinite re-rendering. i tried using `useRef` for `uiData` but it didn't help.
what might be the issue?

Comment: I need to run it locally so that I can find the actual problem, and I might won't, because I don't have the whole codebase. Though, I can tell you what I would do differently, or what I would do to find the problem.
First of all, I would check if this custom hook useDoctorProjections returns a different object instance on every render. Since, you use it inside the effect that sets state that migh be the reason of the infinite re-renders.
The other thing I would do is to gradually start commenting out the lines of code that they might cause re-renders.

Comment: @thandem thanks for your reply, the thing is when i comment out `setUiData` in onSearchSubmit the re-render doesn't happen at all. the dataSource is always same

Comment: The setUiData updates the state, and makes the component to re-render. 
It might though be the first tile of a collapsing domino stracture.
That said, one last thing that I would do, is to replace useState with the suggested for those cases useReducer to have better control over the object.
But still, I don't think that the problem lies there.
Suggestions: Keep the setUIData un-comented, and start comment the effects and other parts. Use 'debugger' inside the components context to observe in steps what is happening inside you component when you trigger those events.